# Windowbuilder pro adding custom jpanel

Tags: eclipse, windowbuilder

just a simple question: I made a custom jpanel putting in just buttons. How do I put this jpanel into my jframe in design view?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Ok i found out the method of adding custom component to WindowBuilder. Silly me, need to build the class and then right click the palatte to add in custom component :)